# Check if file exist on watched folder

Tags: powershell

I want to have a checked folder, but before that I need to check that if a certain file exist within that folder. If it does I need to make some actions, if not make another.

And I need to check if that file exist everytime. So its a running process. I cant just execute once.

Thanks in advance

So far I have this:

```
$root= [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$foldertmp = "$root\UNB\TMP\"
$filter = 'FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT'                             # <-- set this according to your requirements
$PDFDestination = "$root\UNB\NO_PROCESADO\"
#C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\TMP

Write-Host "EL ROOT ES $root" -fore white

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $foldertmp, $filter -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $true              # <-- set this according to your requirements
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

 Write-Host "The file '$name' at '$path'was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore white
 comprobar
 limpia
 printpdf
 renombra
 borrar

}

function comprobar() 
{


    if(!(Test-Path 'C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT')){
    Write-Host "No hay archivo temporal. Proceso correcto" -fore white
    Get-Printer -Name "UNBILLING" | select Name, PrinterStatus, JobCount, DriverName 
    }

    if((Test-Path 'C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT')){
    Write-Host "Archivo existe. Error" -fore white
    Get-Printer -Name "UNBILLING" | select Name, PrinterStatus, JobCount, DriverName 
    limpia
    renombra_noprocesado
    borrar
    }

}


function limpia() 
{
    $regex = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]
    write-host "FUNCION LIMPIA ARCHIVO TXT" -fore white 
    $a = get-content $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.txt | 
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^[.! pÿ>i@]{1,}', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^0 {2,}', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '>', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { ($_.TrimEnd() )}  | Where-Object {$_ -ne ""} |
        set-content $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt

}

function printpdf()
{
    write-host "FUNCION IMPRIMIR A PDF" -fore white 
    start-process -filepath "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt" -verb print 

}

function borrar()
{
write-host "FUNCION BORRAR" -fore white 
#Start-Sleep -s 2
Remove-Item $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.txt
}

function renombra()
{
write-host "FUNCION RENOMBRAR ARCHIVO" -fore white   
Get-Item $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {("print-"+'{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}{1}' -f (Get-Date),".txt")}
}

function renombra_noprocesado()
{
write-host "FUNCION RENOMBRAR ARCHIVO NO PROCESADO" -fore white 

    Move-Item $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt $PDFDestination 
    Get-Item  $root\UNB\NO_PROCESADO\FACT_FINAL.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {("print-"+'{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}{1}' -f (Get-Date),".txt")}

}
```

Comment: Please. This is killing me. I need to keep the script running but I also have to check for existing file while its running.